# What is the radius of the circle in cm?

Tags: geometry, circles

The rectangle at the corner measures `10 cm  * 20 cm`.

The  right bottom corner of the rectangle is also a point on the circumference of the circle.

What is the radius of the circle in cm?
Is the data sufficent to get the radius of circle?

[image]

Comment: @Raskolnikov which 2 solutions?

Comment: Nope, I made a mistake. The problem leads to a quadratic equation, but one of the solutions implies a rectangle with zero area, which should be discarded. So there's only one left.

Comment: Thanks to @MarkBennet , I deleted my wrong answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: with a coordinate system at the center of the circle, the point of intersection of the circle with the rectangle is $(10-r,r-20)$, so
$$
(10-r)^2+(r-20)^2=r^2.
$$

Note also, that to be in the situation imposed by the diagram, you must have $r>20$.

Comment: can you please explain your equation?

Comment: @vikiiii The equation of a circle with center $(a,b)$ ($(0,0)$ here) and radius $r$ is $(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=r^2$. We know the point $(x,y)=(10-r, r-20)$ is on our circle; so, this point satisfies the equation $x^2+y^2=r^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $R$ denote the radius, and let $w$ and $h$ be the width and the height of the rectangle.

Consider right triangle, formed by the center of the circle $O$, point where the rectangle touches the circle $A$ and the point $B$ - projection of $A$ on the horizontal diameter.

Then, by Pythagorean theorem:
$$ \begin{eqnarray}
     R^2 &=& (R-w)^2 + (R-h)^2 \\
     R^2 &=& 2 R^2 - 2 R(w+h) + w^2 + h^2
 \end{eqnarray}
$$
It remains to solve this quadratic equation, and choose the appropriate root (considering the special case of a square, when $w=h$, helps):
$$
    R = w + h + \sqrt{2 w h}
$$

Answer (score 1):

$$r^2=x^2+y^2 \tag{1}$$
$r=y+20$ and $r=x+10$ therefore 
$$y+20=x+10 \quad \mbox{then } \quad y=x-10 \tag{2}$$
Substitute $(2)$ into $(1)$
$$(r+10)^2=x^2+(x-10)^2$$
$$x^2+20x+100=x^2+x^2-20x+100$$
$$X^2=40x$$
$$x=40$$
Then substitute $x=40$ into $(2)$
$$y=40-10$$
$$y=30$$
substitute $x=40$ and $Y=30$ into $(1)$
$$r^2=(40)^2+(30)^2$$
$$r=50\rm{cm}.$$

Answer (score 0):

[image]

In the circle shown above the triangles $\triangle AGT$ and $\triangle TKX$ are similar.

We know $BC=10$ and $AG=20$

Let $CK=y$ and radius of the circle $BX=R$

In the similar triangles $\triangle AGT$ and $\triangle TKX$ we have,

$\frac{AG}{GT}=\frac{TK}{KX}$

$\frac{20}{10+y}=\frac{R-20}{R-(10+y)}$

i.e. $CK=y=10$

$GT=BK=BC+CK=10+10$

$AT=\sqrt{{AG}^2+{GT}^2}=20\sqrt{2}$

${TK}^2+{KX}^2={TX}^2$

$(R-20)^2+(R-20)^2={TX}^2$

**TO BE CONTINUED**